# Stop bringing Chromium to front

Tags: macos, puppeteer, chromium

My tests run Puppeteer in `headless: false` mode and open several tabs.
If I am in another app window - whenever it opens a new tab - it focuses Chromium into view.
That is annoying. Is there any way to make it run in the background?

I'm on macOS 10.14

Comment: It's very annoying and basically doesn't let you do anything else. I use the method I mentioned in the answer and works for the things I do. Interested to know if it works in your setup (multiple tabs) too.

Answer (score 10):

1. Go to `Chromium.app/Contents` folder and open `Info.plist` in an editor.
   (for puppeteer it should be: `node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/mac-XXXXXX/chrome-mac/Chromium.app/Contents/Info.plist`)
2. After the first `<dict>` and before the `<key>` add the following:

```
    <key>LSBackgroundOnly</key>
    <string>True</string>
```

3. Save and close it.

Now Chromium should run in the background and won't steal the focus.

Source: [Keep applications from stealing focus when opening in OS X](https://www.cnet.com/news/keep-applications-from-stealing-focus-when-opening-in-os-x/)

Comment: It works... kinda. But after this it's impossible to switch to that Chromium instance via app switcher anymore. What I essentially need is make it open 3-4 tabs in the background (I'll browse SO in the meanwhile), and when it's finished - I need to interact with those tabs.

Comment: @avalanche1 maybe I'm missing something here but this shouldn't affect arbitrary interaction with the app. on my side, when chromium opens and doesn't steal focus, I can easily switch back to it anytime.

Comment: I cannot. What version of mac os are you on?

Comment: @avalanche1 10.15.3

Comment: ok, maybe that's the reason; I'm on 10.14. And I don't have Chromium (opened in the way you had proposed) in my App Switcher (cmd+tab)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're doing with the Website, it looks like it may not be feasible:

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2656