# How to keep puppeteer browser running background without jumping to foreground?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

When use `puppeteer` to scrape a bunch of sites via a `for-loop`, whenever a new page is created, the browser would jump to the foreground, which hinders me from doing other things on my computer.

Even I set the following args, it still doesn't work, so how could I keep the browser running quietly without jumping to foreground and interupting me?

I need to run in `headful` mode, not `headless` mode.

```
headless: false,
args: [
                '--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36',
                '--disable-background-timer-throttling',
                '--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows',
                '--disable-renderer-backgrounding',
            ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Puppeteer - Stop bringing Chromium to front](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60321191/puppeteer-stop-bringing-chromium-to-front)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Open Chromium's `Info.plist` (you may find it here `node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/mac-XXXXXX/chrome-mac/Chromium.app/Contents/Info.plist`) in an editor and add the following piece after the first `<dict>` and before `<key>`:

```
<key>LSBackgroundOnly</key>
<string>True</string>
```

This works on any OS X application.

Source: [Keep applications from stealing focus when opening in OS X](https://www.cnet.com/news/keep-applications-from-stealing-focus-when-opening-in-os-x/)

Comment: I actually use Chrome and a custom user_data folder, and I added the above key to the Info.plist (inside user_data folder), doesn't work

Comment: @avocado you should add it to Chrome then, find chrome's info.plist which is probably at `path/to/Chrome.app/Contents/Info.plist`, not user_data folder.

Comment: any way to do this for linux?

Comment: how to do it on Windows?

Comment: I call the Chrome Canary executable on Mac, and added this into the .app/Contents/Info.plist, but it still captures focus.

Comment: Related discussion on github.com/puppeteer with possible Windows solution, https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6606

Answer (score -2):

You can use:
`headless: true`.

I did this:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    executablePath: 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Chrome-win/chrome.exe'
});
```

Comment: Please write your answer in English, as Stack Overflow is an [English-only site](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680).

Comment: I surely know what headless looks like, but this is not the solution I wanted

Comment: Please read "[answer]" and "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34492616)