# How can I stop headful puppeteer stealing focus on launch under Linux?

Tags: node.js, linux, gtk, puppeteer, cinnamon

I'm running puppeteer through node on Linux Mint Cinnamon (GTK based).  When my headfull puppeteer launches, it jumps to the foreground and steals focus.

How can I stop this from happening?

I found this question: [How to keep puppeteer browser running background without jumping to foreground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60587166/how-to-keep-puppeteer-browser-running-background-without-jumping-to-foreground)

But it only seems to apply to MacOS.

(headlessness is not an option).

Comment: it doesn't have a similar Chrome/Chromium specific prevention as in the case of OSX. the closest you can get on Linux Mint with Cinnamon is the infamous _"Prevent focus stealing"_ setting which hasn't worked for a long time but seems to be partially [fixed and shipped with Cinnamon 5.x](https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/issues/8059). but when will it be fixed for good is not yet known (the linked GitHub issue needs to be followed).